# Shopware 6 Updates only via console? (after 6.5)

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Are Shopware updates from Shopware 6.5 onwards only possible via the console and no longer through the system settings in the shop administration?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [new web-based installer](https://www.shopware.com/en/news/the-improved-shopware-installer/). However, if possible, it's strongly recommended to update using `composer` in the CLI. The new web-installer is basically doing the same under the hood, but doing it manually in the CLI will remove all the risks coming with request based runtime restrictions. If you haven't done so already, [migrate to the Symfony flex template](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/installation/template#how-do-i-migrate-from-production-template-to-symfony-flex). Once that is done, [updating](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/installation/template#update-shopware) should just be a matter of executing a couple of commands.